# part id number input design with single char placing and highlight

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm building a page in my Angular app that contains input fields. One of the fields is an identification number that needs to be formatted this way
[image]

Can anyone refer me to a similar design source/tutorial or advise how to design it myself.

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="text" class="identification-box">`

with following attributes to `.identification-box` in css

```
    width: 48px;
    border: none;
    background: #FBFBFB;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #D8DDE3;
```

This is one box, you will have to repeat in ngFor, just being verbose here.